# Parse a JSON array

Tags: json, swift, parsing

i am working on a way to parse json from the web in my app.

Source: http://api.randomuser.me/

My Code:

```
var bytes: NSMutableData?

@IBAction func loadJson(sender: AnyObject) {

    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://api.randomuser.me/")!)

    let loader = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)

}

func connection(didReceiveResponse: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse!) {

        self.bytes = NSMutableData()

}

func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData conData: NSData!) {

        self.bytes?.appendData(conData)

}

func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {

    let jsonResult: Dictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(self.bytes!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

    let results: NSArray = jsonResult["results"]! as! NSArray

    println(results)

    for result in results {

        // Works
        println(result)

        // Works
        println(result["seed"])

        // Does not work !!! why?
        println(result["user"]["email"])

    }

}
```

Why can't I get the email from the array?

If you want you can take a look at the json in the link above.

Comment: Rather than linking to the JSON, please include it directly in the question.  I deleted the opinion-based part of your question in the interest of keeping your question on-topic.  But ultimately, this question is still borderline.  Can you elaborate on `// Does not work !!! why?` What does "does not work" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) you can handle your JSON data easily this way:

```
@IBAction func loadJson(sender: AnyObject) {

    let baseURL = NSURL(string: "http://api.randomuser.me/")
    let userData = NSData(contentsOfURL: baseURL!)

    let json = JSON(data: userData!)
    let seeds = json["results"][0]["seed"].stringValue
    let email = json["results"][0]["user"]["email"].stringValue
    println(seeds)    //1bbefb89fc47c81501
    println(email)    //luz.hidalgo44@example.com
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: thanks this lib is great, but how to deal with basic authentification on the web server?

Comment: i mean, if there is username and a password required for access*

Comment: you can save username and password with this and you can use it.

Comment: oh sorry, i meant: if i request the web server to load json, but the webserver requires username and password for authentification. you know what i mean?

Comment: Yes I understand now but I have no Idea about it.Feel free to ask another question with your issue..:)